# How to Authenticate an AXIS camera with ONVIF

Tags: c#, onvif

I have 3 ONVIF cameras (Bosch, Pansonic and AXIS). I find the cameras using WS-Discovery and can get information from the cameras using GetDeviceInformation. My problem is that the AXIS camera returns (400) Bad Request when I try to get information from it, the two others work like a charm.

I have installed ONVIF Device Manager from SourceForge. If I enter login credientials in the program, I can stream live video from the AXIS camera. If I don't enter any login credientials, I can find the camera, but not stream any video. So based on this I concluded that the camera is correct configured.

I think it has something to do with login credientials on the binding, but can't figure out what is wrong.

My code looks like this

```
private void CustomBinding2()
{
        try
        {
            const string SERVICE_ADDRESS_DIRECT = "http://192.168.1.72/onvif/device_service"; //400 bad request
            const string USERNAME = "cbk";
            const string PASSWORD = "12";

            HttpTransportBindingElement httpTransportBindingElement = new HttpTransportBindingElement();
            httpTransportBindingElement.MaxReceivedMessageSize = Int32.MaxValue;
            httpTransportBindingElement.KeepAliveEnabled = false;
            httpTransportBindingElement.MaxBufferSize = Int32.MaxValue;
            httpTransportBindingElement.ProxyAddress = null;
            httpTransportBindingElement.BypassProxyOnLocal = true;
            httpTransportBindingElement.UseDefaultWebProxy = false;
            httpTransportBindingElement.TransferMode = TransferMode.StreamedResponse;
            httpTransportBindingElement.AuthenticationScheme = AuthenticationSchemes.Basic;

            TextMessageEncodingBindingElement messegeElement = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement();
            messegeElement.MessageVersion = MessageVersion.CreateVersion(EnvelopeVersion.Soap12, AddressingVersion.None);

            CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding(messegeElement, httpTransportBindingElement);
            binding.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30.0);
            binding.OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30.0);
            binding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10.0);
            binding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3.0);

            EndpointAddress serviceAddress = new EndpointAddress(SERVICE_ADDRESS_DIRECT);

            ChannelFactory<Device> channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<Device>(binding, serviceAddress);
            channelFactory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = USERNAME;
            channelFactory.Credentials.UserName.Password = PASSWORD;

            Device channel = channelFactory.CreateChannel();

            string model, firmwareVersion, serialNumber, hardwareId;
            channel.GetDeviceInformation(out model, out firmwareVersion, out serialNumber, out hardwareId);
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Model: {0}", model));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved the problem...

One of the things that cheated me the most, was that the AXIS camera and the Client (PC) had to be time synchronous within +-5 sec. If I change the PC time, I just get the 400 bad request back. If the time matches everything works!!!

```
            DateTime UTCTime = DateTime.UtcNow;

            tbInfo.AppendText(string.Format("Client Local Time: {0}\n", DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss")));
            tbInfo.AppendText(string.Format("Client UTC Time: {0}\n", UTCTime.ToString("HH:mm:ss")));
            tbInfo.AppendText("\n\n");

            HttpTransportBindingElement httpTransport = new HttpTransportBindingElement();

            TransportSecurityBindingElement transportSecurity = new TransportSecurityBindingElement();
            transportSecurity.EndpointSupportingTokenParameters.SignedEncrypted.Add(new UsernameTokenParameters());
            transportSecurity.AllowInsecureTransport = true;
            transportSecurity.IncludeTimestamp = false;

            TextMessageEncodingBindingElement textMessageEncoding = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap12, Encoding.UTF8);

            CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding(transportSecurity, textMessageEncoding, httpTransport);

            EndpointAddress serviceAddress = new EndpointAddress(addressDirect);
            ChannelFactory<Device> channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<Device>(binding, serviceAddress);

            UsernameClientCredentials credentials = new UsernameClientCredentials(new UsernameInfo(username, password));

            channelFactory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Remove(typeof(ClientCredentials));
            channelFactory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(credentials);

            Device channel = channelFactory.CreateChannel();

            var unitTime = channel.GetSystemDateAndTime(new GetSystemDateAndTimeRequest());
            tbInfo.AppendText(string.Format("Camera Local Time: {0}:{1}:{2}\n", unitTime.SystemDateAndTime.LocalDateTime.Time.Hour, unitTime.SystemDateAndTime.LocalDateTime.Time.Minute, unitTime.SystemDateAndTime.LocalDateTime.Time.Second));
            tbInfo.AppendText(string.Format("Camera UTC Time: {0}:{1}:{2}\n", unitTime.SystemDateAndTime.UTCDateTime.Time.Hour, unitTime.SystemDateAndTime.UTCDateTime.Time.Minute, unitTime.SystemDateAndTime.UTCDateTime.Time.Second));

            var info = channel.GetDeviceInformation(new GetDeviceInformationRequest());
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Model: {0}", info.Model));
```

Comment: could you provide more information about the UsernameTokenParameters class used in this code snippet? I can't find where this class comes from...